# MySql InnoDB contention issue with multiple readers and writers

Tags: mysql, innodb

With InnoDB, is there contention issue if there is one process reads from a table while another process writes to the same table?

Comment: `adaptive hash index` has contention issues - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html. I have faced this issue, cant not exactly remember the scenario  but if you have a huge size of index and this option enabled then you might be facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is contention.  But InnoDB tries very hard to (1) minimize the impact on the user, and (2) resolve contention that leads to 'conflict'.

Readers hang onto the rows they are looking at, but only enough to prevent writes from changing the value before they are finished.  (This is a long, complex, topic, involving "transaction isolation modes", etc.)

Writers block rows to prevent other writes from stepping on their toes.

If two threads try to touch the same row, one of them may be forced to wait until the other finishes its 'transaction'.

In a more extreme case, where each thread would be waiting for the other, a "deadlock" is discovered.  This leads to one transaction being "rolled back".

Bottom line:  Contention is rarely an issue.  However, you should check for errors after every SQL statement, just in case there is a deadlock.